# How could I remove duplicated sections in Ruby DSL

Tags: ruby, money-rails

My current config format seems so redundant. How could I convert it into the next expected config format?

My expected config is:

```
MoneyRails.configure do |config|

    register_currency("TWD", 100)
    register_currency("USD", 100)
    ....
end
```

My current config is:

```
MoneyRails.configure do |config|

  config.register_currency = {
    :priority            => 1,
    :iso_code            => "TWD",
    :name                => "TWD",
    :symbol              => "NT$ ",
    :symbol_first        => true,
    :subunit             => "Subcent",
    :subunit_to_unit     => 100,
    :thousands_separator => ",",
    :decimal_mark        => "."
  }

  config.register_currency = {
    :priority            => 1,
    :iso_code            => "USD",
    :name                => "USD",
    :symbol              => "$ ",
    :symbol_first        => true,
    :subunit             => "Subcent",
    :subunit_to_unit     => 100,
    :thousands_separator => ",",
    :decimal_mark        => "."
  }

  config.register_currency = {
    :priority            => 1,
    :iso_code            => "SGD",
    :name                => "SGD",
    :symbol              => "$ ",
    :symbol_first        => true,
    :subunit             => "Subcent",
    :subunit_to_unit     => 100,
    :thousands_separator => ",",
    :decimal_mark        => "."
  }

  config.register_currency = {
    :priority            => 1,
    :iso_code            => "THB",
    :name                => "THB",
    :symbol              => "$ ",
    :symbol_first        => true,
    :subunit             => "Subcent",
    :subunit_to_unit     => 100,
    :thousands_separator => ",",
    :decimal_mark        => "."
  }

  config.register_currency = {
    :priority            => 1,
    :iso_code            => "AUD",
    :name                => "AUD",
    :symbol              => "$ ",
    :symbol_first        => true,
    :subunit             => "Subcent",
    :subunit_to_unit     => 100,
    :thousands_separator => ",",
    :decimal_mark        => "."
  }

  config.register_currency = {
    :priority            => 1,
    :iso_code            => "KRW",
    :name                => "KRW",
    :symbol              => "$ ",
    :symbol_first        => true,
    :subunit             => "Subcent",
    :subunit_to_unit     => 100,
    :thousands_separator => ",",
    :decimal_mark        => "."
  }

  ...

end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What happened when you tried reducing from your current to your desired version? I see no problem, just a wish list. We'd like to see what you tried to do and your explanation of why it's not working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
default_options = {
    :priority            => 1,
    :iso_code            => 'USD',
    :name                => 'USD',
    :symbol              => "$ ",
    :symbol_first        => true,
    :subunit             => "Subcent",
    :subunit_to_unit     => 100,
    :thousands_separator => ",",
    :decimal_mark        => "."
}

MoneyRails.configure do |config|
  config.register_currency = default_options
  config.register_currency = default_options.merge(name: 'TWD', iso_code: 'TWD', symbol: 'NT$')
  config.register_currency = default_options.merge(name: 'THB', iso_code: 'THB')
  config.register_currency = default_options.merge(name: 'SGD')
end
```

The `merge` method merges two Hash instances and returns an Hash object. If the second Hash object has some keys matching  the first then the second Hash's `key => value` replaces/overrides the former one.

Answer (score 1):

What about creating this little module? You only need to add an extra attribute with your config object:

```
module MoneyRails
  module MyApp
    def register_currency(config, name, subunit_to_unit)
      config.register_currency(options_hash(name, subunit_to_unit))
    end

    private

    def options_hash(name, subunit_to_unit)
      {
        :priority            => 1,
        :iso_code            => name,
        :name                => name,
        :symbol              => "$ ",
        :symbol_first        => true,
        :subunit             => "Subcent",
        :subunit_to_unit     => subunit_to_unit,
        :thousands_separator => ",",
        :decimal_mark        => "."
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Note I'm namespacing it in order not to pollute the base namespace. Change that to your leisure.

And then:

```
include MoneyRails::MyApp

MoneyRails.configure do |config|

    register_currency(config, "TWD", 100)
    register_currency(config, "USD", 100)
    ....
end
```

Comment: you are accessing `instance` method via `class` method way

Answer (score 0):

There are relatively few exceptions, so I would be inclined to put those  in a file, one line per currency, together with the currency name abbreviation. For example, one line might be:

```
TWD SYM:"NT$ "
```

(or `TWD SYM:NT$` if all values of `:symbol` have one space at the end).

Most lines would have only the currency abbreviation, e.g.:

```
USD
```

You would then read and parse that file into an array such as the following:

```
specific_bits = [
  ["TWD", { symbol: "NT$ " }],
  ["USD", {}],
  ["SGD", {} ],
  ["THB", { subunit_to_unit: 999 }],
  ["AUD", {}],
  ["KRW", {}],
  ["XYZ", { symbol: "XT$ ", subunit_to_unit: -5 }],
]
```

Then define:

```
BASE_HASH = {
  priority:            1,
  symbol:              "$ ",
  symbol_first:        true,
  subunit:             "Subcent",
  subunit_to_unit:     100,
  thousands_separator: ",",
  decimal_mark:        "."
}
```

This allows you to construct the hashes very simply:

```
specific_bits.map do |name, exceptions|
  h = { :iso_code => name, :name => name }
  exceptions.each { |k,v| h[k] = v }
  BASE_HASH.merge h
end
  #=> [{:priority=>1, :symbol=>"NT$ ", :symbol_first=>true,    :subunit=>"Subcent",
  #    :subunit_to_unit=>100, :thousands_separator=>",", :decimal_mark=>".",
  #    :iso_code=>"TWD", :name=>"TWD"},
  #    {...
  #    ...]
```

If you'd prefer the keys to be in a specific order, that's a minor tweak.